# Ribbon fails: Ribbon <Tab> node must have a <Scaling> subnode

Tags: 2010, ribbon, elements-xml

I am in big trouble. I have created two ribbons and both doesn't work. I allways get the following failure message:

> System.ArgumentException: Ribbon `<Tab>` node must have a `<Scaling>` subnode.

I have already created the ribbon more than once, followed tutorials and howto's. But I don't know whats wrong. I have a scaling tag and I know, that the failure occures when I have problems with the size. But I have created a template for each Group in the tab.

Here is one of my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar"
                Title="Tab for the tourenplan view."
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Tabs._children">
          <Tab Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar"
               Title="Optionen"
               Description="Tab for the tourenplan view."
               Sequence="990">
            <Scaling Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Scaling">
              <MaxSize Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Views.MaxSize"
                       GroupId="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Views"
                       Size="ThreeLarge" />
              <MaxSize Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Allocations.MaxSize"
                       GroupId="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Allocations"
                       Size="FiveLarge" />
              <MaxSize Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Times.MaxSize"
                       GroupId="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Times"
                       Size="SixLarge" />
              <MaxSize Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Delete.MaxSize"
                       GroupId="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Delete"
                       Size="OneLarge" />
              <Scale Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Views.Scaling.CalendarScaling"
                     GroupId="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Views"
                     Size="ThreeLarge" />
              <Scale Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Allocations.Scaling.CalendarScaling"
                     GroupId="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Allocations"
                     Size="FiveLarge" />
              <Scale Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Times.Scaling.CalendarScaling"
                     GroupId="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Times"
                     Size="SixLarge" />
              <Scale Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Delete.Scaling.CalendarScaling"
                     GroupId="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Delete"
                     Size="OneLarge" />
            </Scaling>
            <Groups Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Groups">
              <!-- Views Group -->
              <Group Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Views"
                     Command="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Views"
                     Description="Contains view items"
                     Title="Ansichten"
                     Sequence="10"
                     Template="Ribbon.Templates.TourenplanView.Views">
                <Controls Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Views.Controls">
                  <Button Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Views.DayView"
                          Command="OpenDayView"
                          Sequence="10"
                          Image16by16="/_layouts/images/MAN/day.png"
                          Image32by32="/_layouts/images/MAN/day.png"
                          LabelText="Tag"
                          TemplateAlias="view1"/>
                  <Button Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Views.WeekView"
                          Command="OpenWeekView"
                          Sequence="20"
                          Image16by16="/_layouts/images/MAN/WorkingWeek.png"
                          Image32by32="/_layouts/images/MAN/WorkingWeek.png"
                          LabelText="Woche"
                          TemplateAlias="view2"/>
                  <Button Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Views.MonthView"
                          Command="OpenMonthView"
                          Sequence="30"
                          Image16by16="/_layouts/images/MAN/Month.png"
                          Image32by32="/_layouts/images/MAN/Month.png"
                          LabelText="Monat"
                          TemplateAlias="view3"/>
                </Controls>
              </Group>
              <!-- Allocations Group -->
              <Group Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Allocations"
                     Command="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Allocations"
                     Title="Tourenzuordnung"
                     Sequence="20"
                     Template="Ribbon.Templates.TourenplanView.Allocations">
                <Controls Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Allocations.Controls">
                  <Button Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Allocations.TourOne"
                          Command="AllocateToTour1"
                          Sequence="10"
                          Image16by16="/_layouts/images/GROUP.gif"
                          Image32by32="/_layouts/images/GROUP.gif"
                          LabelText="Tour 1"
                          TemplateAlias="allocation1"/>
                  <Button Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Allocations.TourTwo"
                          Command="AllocateToTour2"
                          Sequence="20"
                          Image16by16="/_layouts/images/GROUP.gif"
                          Image32by32="/_layouts/images/GROUP.gif"
                          LabelText="Tour 2"
                          TemplateAlias="allocation2"/>
                  <Button Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Allocations.TourThree"
                          Command="AllocateToTour3"
                          Sequence="30"
                          Image16by16="/_layouts/images/GROUP.gif"
                          Image32by32="/_layouts/images/GROUP.gif"
                          LabelText="Tour 3"
                          TemplateAlias="allocation3"/>
                  <Button Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Allocations.TourFour"
                          Command="AllocateToTour4"
                          Sequence="40"
                          Image16by16="/_layouts/images/GROUP.gif"
                          Image32by32="/_layouts/images/GROUP.gif"
                          LabelText="Tour 4"
                          TemplateAlias="allocation4"/>
                  <Button Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Allocations.TourFive"
                          Command="AllocateToTour5"
                          Sequence="50"
                          Image16by16="/_layouts/images/GROUP.gif"
                          Image32by32="/_layouts/images/GROUP.gif"
                          LabelText="Tour 5"
                          TemplateAlias="allocation5"/>
                </Controls>
              </Group>
              <!-- Times Group -->
              <Group Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Times"
                     Command="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Times"
                     Title="Minuten"
                     Sequence="30"
                     Template="Ribbon.Templates.TourenplanView.Times">
                <Controls Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Times.Controls">
                  <Button Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Times.PlusFive"
                          Command="PlusFiveMinutes"
                          Sequence="10"
                          Image16by16="/_layouts/images/create_upArrow.png"
                          Image32by32="/_layouts/images/create_upArrow.png"
                          LabelText="+5"
                          TemplateAlias="time1"/>
                  <Button Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Times.PlusTen"
                          Command="PlusTenMinutes"
                          Sequence="20"
                          Image16by16="/_layouts/images/create_upArrow.png"
                          Image32by32="/_layouts/images/create_upArrow.png"
                          LabelText="+10"
                          TemplateAlias="time2"/>
                  <Button Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Times.PlusFifteen"
                          Command="PlusFifteenMinutes"
                          Sequence="30"
                          Image16by16="/_layouts/images/create_upArrow.png"
                          Image32by32="/_layouts/images/create_upArrow.png"
                          LabelText="+15"
                          TemplateAlias="time3"/>
                  <Button Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Times.MinusFive"
                          Command="MinusFiveMinuts"
                          Sequence="40"
                          Image16by16="/_layouts/images/create_defaultDownArrow.png"
                          Image32by32="/_layouts/images/create_defaultDownArrow.png"
                          LabelText="-5"
                          TemplateAlias="time4"/>
                  <Button Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Times.MinusTen"
                          Command="MinusTenMinuts"
                          Sequence="50"
                          Image16by16="/_layouts/images/create_defaultDownArrow.png"
                          Image32by32="/_layouts/images/create_defaultDownArrow.png"
                          LabelText="-10"
                          TemplateAlias="time5"/>
                  <Button Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Times.MinusFifteen"
                          Command="MinusFifteenMinuts"
                          Sequence="60"
                          Image16by16="/_layouts/images/create_defaultDownArrow.png"
                          Image32by32="/_layouts/images/create_defaultDownArrow.png"
                          LabelText="-15"
                          TemplateAlias="time6"/>
                </Controls>
              </Group>
              <Group Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Remove"
                     Command="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Remove"
                     Title="Löschen"
                     Sequence="40"
                     Template="Ribbon.Templates.TourenplanView.Times">
                <Controls Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Remove.Controls">
                  <Button Id="Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Remove.Delete"
                          Command="DeleteFromTour"
                          Sequence="10"
                          Image16by16="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png"
                          Image16by16Top="-112"
                          Image16by16Left="-224"
                          Image32by32="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png"
                          Image32by32Top="-128" 
                          Image32by32Left="-128"
                          LabelText="+5"
                          TemplateAlias="remove"/>
                </Controls>
              </Group>
            </Groups>
          </Tab>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
        <!-- Definition for the template for the Views Group. -->
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
          <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.TourenplanView.Views">
            <Layout Title="ThreeLarge" LayoutTitle="ThreeLarge">
              <Section Alignment="Middle" Type="OneRow">
                <Row>
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="view1" />
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="view2" />
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="view3" />
                </Row>
              </Section>
            </Layout>
          </GroupTemplate>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
        <!-- Definition for the template for the Allocations group -->
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
          <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.TourenplanView.Allocations">
            <Layout Title="FiveLarge" LayoutTitle="FiveLarge">
              <Section Alignment="Middle" Type="OneRow">
                <Row>
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="allocation1" />
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="allocation2" />
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="allocation3" />
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="allocation4" />
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="allocation5" />
                </Row>
              </Section>
            </Layout>
          </GroupTemplate>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
        <!-- Definition for the template for the Times group -->
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
          <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.TourenplanView.Times">
            <Layout Title="SixLarge" LayoutTitle="SixLarge">
              <Section Alignment="Middle" Type="OneRow">
                <Row>
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="time1" />
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="time2" />
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="time3" />
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="time4" />
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="time5" />
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="time6" />
                </Row>
              </Section>
            </Layout>
          </GroupTemplate>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
        <!-- Definition for the template for the Delete group -->
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
          <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.TourenplanView.Delete">
            <Layout Title="OneLarge" LayoutTitle="OneLarge">
              <Section Alignment="Middle" Type="OneRow">
                <Row>
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="remove" />
                </Row>
              </Section>
            </Layout>
          </GroupTemplate>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="OpenDayView"
                          CommandAction="javascript:function OpenDayView()
                                          {
                                            __doPostBack('DayViewPostback','');
                                            RefreshCommandUI();
                                          }
                                          OpenDayView();"
                          EnabledScript="True" />
        <CommandUIHandler Command="OpenWeekView"
                          CommandAction="javascript:function OpenWeekView()
                                          {
                                            __doPostBack('WeekViewPostback','');
                                            RefreshCommandUI();
                                          }
                                          OpenWeekView();"
                          EnabledScript="True" />
        <CommandUIHandler Command="OpenMonthView"
                          CommandAction="javascript:function OpenMonthView()
                                          {
                                            __doPostBack('MonthViewPostback','');
                                            RefreshCommandUI();
                                          }
                                          OpenMonthView();"
                          EnabledScript="True" />
        <CommandUIHandler Command="AllocateToTour1"
                          CommandAction="javascript:function AddToTourOne() {
                                          var argument = '1|' + GetSelectedItems();
                                          __doPostBack('AddToTourPostback', argument);
                                          RefreshCommandUI();
                                        }
                                        AddToTourOne();"
                          EnabledScript="True" />
        <CommandUIHandler Command="AllocateToTour2"
                          CommandAction="javascript:function AddToTourTwo() {
                                          var argument = '2|' + GetSelectedItems();
                                          __doPostBack('AddToTourPostback', argument);
                                          RefreshCommandUI();
                                        }
                                        AddToTourTwo();"
                          EnabledScript="True" />
        <CommandUIHandler Command="AllocateToTour3"
                          CommandAction="javascript:function AddToTourThree() {
                                          var argument = '3|' + GetSelectedItems();
                                          __doPostBack('AddToTourPostback', argument);
                                          RefreshCommandUI();
                                        }
                                        AddToTourThree();"
                          EnabledScript="True" />
        <CommandUIHandler Command="AllocateToTour4"
                          CommandAction="javascript:function AddToTourFour() {
                                          var argument = '4|' + GetSelectedItems();
                                          __doPostBack('AddToTourPostback', argument);
                                          RefreshCommandUI();
                                        }
                                        AddToTourFour();"
                          EnabledScript="True" />
        <CommandUIHandler Command="AllocateToTour5"
                          CommandAction="javascript:function AddToTourFive() {
                                          var argument = '5|' + GetSelectedItems();
                                          __doPostBack('AddToTourPostback', argument);
                                          RefreshCommandUI();
                                        }
                                        AddToTourFive();"
                          EnabledScript="True" />
        <CommandUIHandler Command="PlusFiveMinutes"
                          CommandAction="javascript:function IncreaseDeliveryTimeByFive() {
                                          var argument = '5|' + GetSelectedItems();
                                          __doPostBack('IncreaseDeliveryPostback', argument);
                                          RefreshCommandUI();
                                        }
                                        IncreaseDeliveryTimeByFive();"
                          EnabledScript="True" />
        <CommandUIHandler Command="PlusTenMinutes"
                          CommandAction="javascript:function IncreaseDeliveryTimeByTen() {
                                          var argument = '10|' + GetSelectedItems();
                                          __doPostBack('IncreaseDeliveryPostback', argument);
                                          RefreshCommandUI();
                                        }
                                        IncreaseDeliveryTimeByTen();"
                          EnabledScript="True" />
        <CommandUIHandler Command="PlusFifteenMinutes"
                          CommandAction="javascript:function IncreaseDeliveryTimeByFifteen() {
                                          var argument = '15|' + GetSelectedItems();
                                          __doPostBack('IncreaseDeliveryPostback', argument);
                                          RefreshCommandUI();
                                        }
                                        IncreaseDeliveryTimeByFifteen();"
                          EnabledScript="True" />
        <CommandUIHandler Command="MinusFiveMinutes"
                          CommandAction="javascript:function DecreaseDeliveryTimeByFive() {
                                          var argument = '5|' + GetSelectedItems();
                                          __doPostBack('DecreaseDeliveryPostback', argument);
                                          RefreshCommandUI();
                                        }
                                        DecreaseDeliveryTimeByTen();"
                          EnabledScript="True" />
        <CommandUIHandler Command="MinusTenMinutes"
                          CommandAction="javascript:function DecreaseDeliveryTimeByTen() {
                                          var argument = '10|' + GetSelectedItems();
                                          __doPostBack('DecreaseDeliveryPostback', argument);
                                          RefreshCommandUI();
                                        }
                                        DecreaseDeliveryTimeByTen();"
                          EnabledScript="True" />
        <CommandUIHandler Command="MinusFifteenMinutes"
                          CommandAction="javascript:function DecreaseDeliveryTimeByFifteen() {
                                          var argument = '15|' + GetSelectedItems();
                                          __doPostBack('DecreaseDeliveryPostback', argument);
                                          RefreshCommandUI();
                                        }
                                        DecreaseDeliveryTimeByFifteen();"
                          EnabledScript="True" />
        <CommandUIHandler Command="DeleteFromTour"
                          CommandAction="javascript: function DeleteItems() {
                                          var argument = GetSelectedItems();
                                          __doPostBack('DeletePostback', argument);
                                          RefreshCommandUI();
                                        }
                                        DeleteItems();"
                          EnabledScript="True" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Maybe someone knows what went wrong.

Comment: Omlin Thx for the implementation of the code :)

Answer (score 2):

You have the Id of one group set to `Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Remove`, but the scaling elements points to `Ribbon.CateringService.TourenplanView.Calendar.Delete`. `Remove` vs `Delete`!

Comment: Ok, thank you for that but it havn't solved it. I checked all the id's and relations and now it seems to be right. But it doesn't work too :\

Comment: Have you cleared the IE cache and everything. Start IE in In-Private mode and test it.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your tab ID must be same as you refer in page load or init.That resolved my issue.